# How to use kendo-data-query groupBy with observables

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, angular2-observables

I'm looking for examples of kendo components reading Observables, like this example 
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/data-binding/#toc-async-pipe

But the examples that uses kendo-data-query doesn't have Observables

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/grouping/

Did anyone make one groupBy with Observables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that was on the other side of what I was looking

```
public Autocomplete = (): Observable<any> => {
return this.$http
  .get<any>(this.apiEndpoint + `api/Autocomplete/GetAutocompleteList/`, {
    observe: 'response'
  })
  .pipe(
    map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      return groupBy((<any>res.body.$values).map((item) => {
        return item;
      }), [{ field: "AutoCompleteType" }]);
    }),
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      return observableThrowError(error);
    })
  );
```

};